# Миграция приложения с Delphi 7 на delphi 2007

Tags: отладка, delphi

После миграции приложения(миграция успешная, приложение компилируется, работает правильно, и т. п.) совсем не работают брейкпоинты(только в данном приложении).
После компиляции на против строк появляются "синие точки", как и положено.
Брейкпоинт ставиться на любую из этих точек, и, после билда приложения на нем появляется крестик(недосягаемый код?), и он, естественно, не срабатывает....
С полной уверенностью заявляю, что код, на котором стоит брейкпоинт, выполняется.

Подскажите, как образумить эти "бряки"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте, может есть копия проекта, в путях прописаных у делфи. А лучше уберите все копии на внешний носитель. А когда все заработает, вернете, если надо. )) В делфях от EM я заметил привычку путаться в одноименных файлах.

Да, и еще одно вспомнил: перед RUN сделайте Build, это тоже помогает.

Comment: а что значит "копия проекта в путях"?
все остальное уже пробовал...

Comment: это значит, что в путях Delphi есть путь к копии данного проекта, поэтому отладчик ориентируется на другие файлы в качестве исходников.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте `Project-Options-Compiler-Debug information`. Галка должна стоять.

Comment: стоит(((((